# How to capture image and send its Uri directly to attachment via Email

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have Ui in which I have to capture an image and onActivityResult I have to send it to directly to email, for that I have tried every possible solution on stack but failed every time and its give me couldn't attach error, after a long time of searching and implementing I have found something to check a , If I can read the file or not like this `file.canRead()` it always gives me false. Any solution would be appreciated.

```
private fun sendEmail(liscence: String, desc: String) {`<br>
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)`<br>
        val to = arrayOf("info@gmail.com")`<br>
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to)`

        emailIntent.type = "text/plain";
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        // attachment Uri comes through camera
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imagePath)
        // the mail subject
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Report")
        //email body
        val body = "${liscence} \n ${desc}"
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body)
        //need this to prompts email client only
        emailIntent.type = "message/rfc822";
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."))
    }
```

Comment: For `ACTION_SEND`, if you are using `EXTRA_STREAM`, the MIME type on the `Intent` needs to be the type associated with this stream. Your image is not `text/plain`, nor is it `message/rfc822`. Please change the MIME type that you are using, and only set it once. Also, whatever `imagePath` is may not be correct -- showing how you get the value for `imagePath` may help us determine where your problems lie

Comment: sure here is my code for the imagePath its Uri which I am receiving after capturing the image, that it can you Please tell me which MIMETYPE should I use ?

Comment: **its my simple fun ,to get URI **` private fun getImageUri(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bytes)
        val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.contentResolver, inImage, "Title", null)
        return Uri.parse(path)
    }`

Comment: "Please tell me which MIMETYPE should I use ?" -- you are saving this as a PNG file. The MIME type for PNG is `image/png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here After a lot of research, I have found the solution in the Android documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#GetUri 
Here is my final code for sharing a captured image to Gmail.
this code will go straight to Manifest file you have to use authorities as a valid authority provider.

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.mydomain.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

XML file for the provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<files-path name="image_picked" path="picked/"/>
<external-path name="*" path="Pictures/"/>
</paths>
```

Function to SendImage as an attachment.

```
    private fun sendEmail() {
    val contentUri = 
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!,
            "yourPackageAndThen.com.mydomain.fileprovider", 
    File(PATH OF IMAGE or FILE ));

    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

    //need this to prompts email client only
    emailIntent.type = "message/rfc822";
    val to = arrayOf("EMAIL ID TO SEND")
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to)
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

    // attachment Uri comes through camera
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)

    // the mail subject
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Report")
    //email body
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, MESSAGEforBody)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission to your app and ask this permission from the user in android SDK greater than 23?
Also, if you save your attachment as private, it's not readable for mail. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15961450/9442191) explains this more.

Comment: yup these are the basics things I have already did it manually for double check.